# Change position of checkbox relative to text in Tkinter's Checkbutton

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

How can I change where the text is relative to the checkbox for a Tkinter `Checkbutton`?

By default, the text is to the right of the checkbox. I would like to change that, so the text is on the left or above of the checkbox.

I know this can be done by creating a `Label` with the required text and delicately positioning the two near each other, but I'd prefer to avoid that method.

Some sample code:

```
from Tkinter import * 
root = Tk()
Checkbutton(root, text="checkButon Text").grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you can't change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't think you can do it *directly*, but you can do something that looks as it should. It is the Label-solution, but I altered it slightly, so the resulting compound of `Checkbutton` and `Label` is treated as a single Widget as wrapped in a `Frame`.

```
from Tkinter import *

class LabeledCheckbutton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(self)
        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.checkbutton.grid(row=0, column=1)


root = Tk()
labeledcb = LabeledCheckbutton(root)
labeledcb.label.configure(text="checkButton Text")
labeledcb.grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

When you create multiple frames (with their respective content - `Checkbutton` and `Label`) you can handle them easily. That way you would just have to position the Frames like you would do it with the Checkbuttons.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like overkill to me. Essentially all you are doing is creating a `Label` and placing it the left column and then placing the `Checkbutton` in the right column. This can simply be done to begin with without the need for a class like this.