# TK python checkbutton RTL

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, right-to-left, tkinter.checkbutton

I have a checkbutton:

```py
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
Checkbutton(master, text="Here...").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
mainloop()
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

I tried to move the checkbutton to the other side (to support RTL languages), so it'll be like:

`Here...[]`

I know that I can draw a label next to the checkbutton, but this way clicking the text won't effect the checkbutton.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745824/change-position-of-checkbox-relative-to-text-in-tkinters-checkbutton . Though, now I realize - it's your last sentence that covers this... Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [bind the left mouse button click event of the label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504571/clickable-tkinter-labels), to a lambda construct that [toggles](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm#Tkinter.Checkbutton.toggle-method) the checkbutton -:

```
label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x : check_button.toggle())
```

The label can then be placed before the checkbutton using grid(as mentioned in the OP at the end) -:

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

l1 = Label(master, text = "Here...")
cb = Checkbutton(master)
l1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
cb.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky=W)

l1.bind("<Button-1>", lambda x : cb.toggle())
mainloop()
```

This will toggle, the checkbutton even if the label is clicked.

**OUTPUT** -:

[image: OUTPUT]

---

**NOTE:**

The checkbutton, has to now be fetched as an object(`cb`), to be used in the lambda construct for the label's bind function callback argument. Thus, it is gridded in the next line. It is generally a good practice to manage the geometry separately, which can prevent error such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) one.

---

Also, as mentioned in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745824/change-position-of-checkbox-relative-to-text-in-tkinters-checkbutton) linked by [@Alexander B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3500157/alexander-b) in the comments, if this assembly is to be used multiple times, it can also be made into a class of it's own that inherits from the `tkinter.Frame` class -:

```
class LabeledCheckbutton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, text = ""):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(self)
        self.label = Label(self, text = text)
        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.checkbutton.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.label.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x : self.checkbutton.toggle())
        return
    
    pass
```

Using this with grid as the geometry manager, would make the full code look like this -:

```
from tkinter import *

class LabeledCheckbutton(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, text = ""):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.checkbutton = Checkbutton(self)
        self.label = Label(self, text = text)
        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        self.checkbutton.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        self.label.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x : self.checkbutton.toggle())
        return
    
    pass

master = Tk()
lcb = LabeledCheckbutton(master, text = "Here...")
lcb.grid(row = 0, sticky = W)

mainloop()
```

The output of the above code remains consistent with that of the first approach. The only difference is that it is now more easily scalable, as an object can be created whenever needed and the same lines of code need not be repeated every time.

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `ttk.Checkbutton` which you can change its layout using `ttk.Style().layout(...)`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

master = tk.Tk()

s = ttk.Style()
# create a custom Checkbutton style with reverse order of label and indicator
s.layout('right.TCheckbutton',
   [('Checkbutton.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [
      ('Checkbutton.focus', {
         'side': 'left', 'sticky': 'w', 'children': [('Checkbutton.label', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]
      }),
      ('Checkbutton.indicator', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})
   ]})]
)

ttk.Checkbutton(master, text='Here...', style='right.TCheckbutton').grid(padx=20, pady=10)

master.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]